# Managing IIS log files over multiple subdomains

Tags: iis, log-files, subdomain

I have enabled logging of the site folder which contains the files of multiple subdomains. When I look at the log, i see the cs-uri-stem, which gives me the directory and file accessed. I can't tell if these are all for the primary domain, in which case how do i enable the logging for my sub-domains, or, they are already for all domains, in which case how can i enable logging of the full url/sub-domain.

thanks!

Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0 
MicrosoftOfficeWebServer: 5.0_Pub

Windows Servers 2003 R2
Standard Edition
Service Pack 2

Answer (score 1):

Setup the sub-domains as individual sites within IIS, then enable logging on each in turn. Then you'd have separate files for each sub-domain. Or am I missing something?